# Argument of type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: node.js, string, typescript, firebase

Quite A newbie when it comes to error handling.

I'm getting a (Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string')error in  this code

Edit: I decided to add in the entire page of code if that helps you to understand the problem.

```
type AuthClient = Compute | JWT | UserRefreshClient;

function isValidType(type: string): boolean {
  return (
    type === 'IMPORT_DATA' || type === 'EXPORT_MODEL' || type === 'TRAIN_MODEL'
  );
}

/**
 * A function to check & update progress of a long running progression
 * in AutoML.
 */
export const checkOperationProgress = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    const operationType = request.query['type'];
    if (!operationType) {
      response.status(404).json({ error: 'Operation `type` needed' });
      return;
    }
    if (!isValidType(operationType)) {
                         ^^^ ERROR ABOVE
      response.status(400).json({
        error: 'type should be one of IMPORT_DATA, EXPORT_MODEL, TRAIN_MODEL',
      });
      return;
    }
    try {
      const client = await auth.getClient({ scopes: [AUTOML_API_SCOPE] });

      const snapshot = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('operations')
        .where('type', '==', operationType)
        .where('done', '==', false)
        .get();

      if (snapshot.empty) {
        response.status(200).json({
          success: `No pending operations found for type ${operationType}`,
        });
        return;
      }

      // for each operation, check the status
      snapshot.docs.forEach(async doc => {
        await updateOperation(doc, client);
      });

      response.status(200).json({
        success: `${snapshot.docs.length} operations updated: ${operationType}`,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(500).json({ error: err.toJSON() });
    }
  }
);
```

Any idea on what I can do about this?

Comment: from the code, you share I can just say that `dataset` is obviously a string array. So you should probably reduce it to a single string. You also don't return in your second example after sending the error response.

Comment: how are your isValidType and generateLabel function look like?

Comment: hey, apologies. I have added the entire page of code if that helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening and I can't reproduce it.  You *should* have weeded out the possibility of `undefined` by returning in the `if(!operationType)` case.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I have little knowledge on how to achieve that, could you elaborate more on what I should try to do?

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the "type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'" error that you posted and thinking that `operationType` was type `string` | `undefined`.  But now I see the title!  The cause is the same as your other question which I just answered.  The solution is a little different though so I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744124/10431574), the value that you get from `request.query` can be a complicated object and is not always just a `string`.  But `isValidType` requires that you pass a `string` so you get an error.

Your `isValidType` function is checking for strict equality between `type` and your predefined strings, so we can change that function to accept `type: any` and it won't have any impact on its behavior.  Any non-strings are guaranteed to return false.

It doesn't appear to be necessary here, but you could alter the return type so that `isValidType` becomes a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
function isValidType(type: any): type is string { 
   ... 
}
```

It still returns a `boolean` value, but when `true`, typescript now knows that the variable `type` has type `string`.  We could also define the return type such that `type` is known to be one of these three specific string literals.