# Argument of type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: node.js, string, typescript, visual-studio-code

This Error keeps bugging me, a (Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string') error in this code

```
export const generateLabelFile = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    const dataset = request.query['dataset'];
    if (!dataset) {
      response.status(404).json({ error: 'Dataset not found' });
    }
    try {
      const labelsFile = await generateLabel(dataset);
                                               ^^^ ERROR ABOVE
      response.json({ success: `File uploaded to ${labelsFile}` });
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() });
    }
  }
);


async function generateLabel(dataset: string): Promise<String> {
  const storage = new Storage({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
  const prefix = `datasets/${dataset}`;

  // get all images in the dataset
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(AUTOML_BUCKET).getFiles({ prefix });

  const csvRows = files
    .map(file => getMetadata(file.name))
    .filter((metadata): metadata is ImageMetadata => metadata !== null)
    .map(({ label, fullPath }) => `gs://${AUTOML_BUCKET}/${fullPath},${label}`);

  console.log('Total rows in labels.csv:', csvRows.length);

  // No videos found, abort
  if (csvRows.length === 0) {
    throw new Error(`No videos found`);
  }
```

I'm really confused on how I can reslove this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type for `request.query` is `QueryString.ParsedQs` which comes from the [qs package](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/qs/index.d.ts).  This package is able to read and parse complicated query vars and not just "key=value" pairs.  A user could use a URL query like `?dataset[]=first&dataset[]=second`, which would be interpreted as an array `["first", "second"]`.

It is up to you how your program should deal with these inputs.  Do you want to handle them, or throw errors?  You could check if `dataset` is an array of strings and call `generateLabel` on each element.  But the simplest solution is to make sure that `dataset` is a `string` and return an error otherwise.

Note that you need some sort of `return` or `else` before going into the `try`/`catch` block so that you don't call `generateLabel` with non-strings.

```
export const generateLabelFile = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    const dataset = request.query['dataset'];
    if (!dataset) {
      response.status(404).json({ error: 'Dataset not found' });
      return;
    }
    if ( typeof dataset !== "string" ) {
      response.status(500).json({ error: 'Invalid dataset' });
      return;
    }
    try {
      const labelsFile = await generateLabel(dataset);
      response.json({ success: `File uploaded to ${labelsFile}` });
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() });
    }
  }
);
```

Another way to handle this, since you are already using a `try`/`catch` around `generateLabel`, is to validate the `dataset` within the `generateLabel` function.  You would allow the function to accept `dataset: any`, but throw an `Error` if `dataset` is anything other than `string`.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. God bless